# Angular 12. Is it possible to call child component via variable as component selector?

Tags: angular, components

For instance, I have an array in parent component:

```js
arr = [
  'app-component-one',
  'app-component-two',
  'app-component-three'
]
```

And I need to implement something like this in parent component template `.html` (scheme):

```html
<#arr[i]# *ngFor="let ar of arr; index as i;">
</#arr[i]#>
```

Is this possible in Angular 12+?

Answer (score 2):

not like this. Angular should know about statically rendered things on compile time. However there is a possibility to render dynamic component. for example this can be done with the help of `ngComponentOutlet` directive like this:

```
arr = [
  MyComponent1,
  MyComponent2,
]
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let comp of arr">
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="comp"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```